# Passing method as props to all children

Tags: reactjs

Trying to pass the method as props to all children. But on printing the child props in console it is showing undefined.

Console output:

```
Object {openLightbox: undefined, closeLightbox: undefined, setLightboxState: undefined, key: 0}
```

Passing openLightbox, closeLightbox and setLightboxState methods as props to the all the children. Setting it in variable childProps.

```
var Lightbox = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return { display: false };
    },

    componentWillMount: function(){
        if (this.props.data)
            this.setState(this.props.data);
    },

    openLightbox: function(){
        this.setState({display: true});
    },

    closeLightbox: function(){
        this.setState({display: false});
    },

    setLightboxState: function(obj){
        this.setState(obj);
    },

    render: function(){
        var childrenWithProps = this.props.children.map(function(child, i) {
            var childProps = {
                openLightbox: this.openLightbox,
                closeLightbox: this.closeLightbox,
                setLightboxState: this.setLightboxState,
                key: i
            };
            console.log(childProps)
            for (var j in this.state){
                childProps[j] = this.state[j];
            }

            var childWithProps = React.cloneElement(child, childProps);

            return childWithProps;
        });

        return (
            <div>
                {childrenWithProps}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in `.map` refers to global scope(in browser it is `window` or `undefined` if you use `strict mode`) where there are no methods  `openLightbox`, `closeLightbox` etc. You can set `this` for `.map` through second argument

```
this.props.children.map(function(child, i) {
  ...
}, this);
___^^^^_
```

Answer (score 0):

Fitst of all you should not iterate over `this.props.children` directly, React has a top-level API for mapping over this.props.children(https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html).

Then function inside map will have `window` or `undefined` as `this`, so you should use arrow function(=> in ES2015) or .bind(this) to link React Component instance to `this`

`var childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
...
}.bind(this))`