# React onChange is not a function when passing method as props to child component

Tags: reactjs

I am having issues when passing a method down into several child components lower. I need to hold state in the parent component, hence the reason for passing the method down to change the state values in parent. Now I know this has been answered several times before, but everything I read does not work?

Here is what i'm trying to do:

Parent method code (OrderView.js):

```
 handleChargesDateChange = (e) => {
    const date = e.target.value;
    const chargeId = e.target.name;
    console.log(date);
    this.setState({
        updatedChargeDates: [
            ...this.state.updatedChargeDates,
            {[chargeId]: date}
        ]
    })
}
```

This method then gets passed down as props within `render()`:

```
 <Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Column width={16}>
                <OrderSummary
                    order={this.state.order}
                    fuelTypes={this.state.fuelTypes}
                    vehicleClasses={this.state.vehicleClasses}
                    deviceTypes={this.state.deviceTypes}
                    chargeTypes={this.state.chargeTypes}
                    featureTypes={this.state.featureTypes}
                    itemGroups={this.state.itemGroups}
                    itemTypes={this.state.itemTypes}
                    **updateChargeDates={this.handleChargesDateChange}**
                />
            </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
```

Then within `OrderSummary` I receive the props as follows and again pass this down to another Child component:

```
const updateChargeDates = this.props;

    console.log("Itemsssss " + this.props.order.items);
    const panes = [];
    if (this.props.order.devices.length > 0) {
        panes.push({
            menuItem: 'Devices', render: () => <DevicesTab
                devices={this.props.order.devices || []}
                fuelTypes={this.props.fuelTypes || []}
                vehicleClasses={this.props.vehicleClasses || []}
                deviceTypes={this.props.deviceTypes || []}
                chargeTypes={this.props.chargeTypes || []}
                featureTypes={this.props.featureTypes || []}
            />
        });
    }

    if (this.props.order.items.length > 0) {
        panes.push({
            menuItem: 'Additional Items', render: () => <ItemsTab
                items={this.props.order.items || []}
                itemGroups={this.props.itemGroups || []}
                itemTypes={this.props.itemTypes || []}
                chargeTypes={this.props.chargeTypes || []}
                **updateChargeDates={updateChargeDates}**
            />
        })
    }
```

Again, I then pass this down to another child into the `ItemsTab` component:

```
 render() {
    const { items, itemGroups, itemTypes, chargeTypes, updateChargeDates } = this.props;
    return <Tab.Pane className='no-border'>
        {items.length > 0 && <Grid>
            <Grid.Row columns={2}>
                <Grid.Column>
                    <ItemGroup
                        itemOrder={items[this.state.currentItem] || {}}
                        itemGroups={itemGroups || []}
                        itemTypes={itemTypes || []}
                    />
                </Grid.Column>
                <Grid.Column>
                    <Charges
                        charges={items[this.state.currentItem].charges || {}}
                        chargeTypes={chargeTypes || []}
                        handleDateChange={this.handleChange}
                        **updateChargeDates={updateChargeDates}**
                    />
                </Grid.Column>
            </Grid.Row>
```

Then finally, in the `Charges` component I try and use the method to just simply update a date:

```
 render() {
 const {charges, chargeTypes, updateChargeDates} = this.props;
 if (charges.length === 0) { return null; }

return <Form>
    <h3>Charges</h3>
    {charges.map(charge => {
        console.log(charge);
        const chargeType = chargeTypes.find(type => type.code === charge.type) || {};
        return <Grid>
            <Grid.Row columns={2}>
                <Grid.Column>
                    <Form.Input
                        key={charge.id}
                        label={chargeType.description || charge.type}
                        value={Number(charge.amount).toFixed(2)}
                        readOnly
                        width={6} />
                </Grid.Column>
                <Grid.Column>
                    <DateInput
                        name={charge.id}
                        selected={this.state.newDate}
                        **onChange={updateChargeDates}**
                        value={charge.effectiveDate}
                    />
                </Grid.Column>
            </Grid.Row>
        </Grid>
    })}
    <Divider hidden />
    <br />
</Form>
}
```

NOTE: I have highlighted the bits of code I care about with `**`

The error I am receiving in the browser console is as follows:

[image]

Now I know generally this error occurs when you dont `bind` the method to the class, but I am using the => ES6 syntax which I thought does not require this? I have even tried adding the binding to the parent component as follows:
`this.handleChargesDateChange = this.handleChargesDateChange.bind(this);`

But again this does not work. I have tried the following resources but no luck:

[Passing props down to childs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241912/passing-method-as-props-to-all-children)

[OnCHange is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39588855/react-onchange-is-not-a-function)

Can someone PLEASE explain where im going wrong? As ive benn trying this for hours now and no luck :/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're incorrectly assigning a prop here:

```
const updateChargeDates = this.props;
```

Change it to

```
const { updateChargeDates } = this.props;
```

or

```
const updateChargeDates = this.props.updateChargeDates;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply, but this still does not work :/

Comment: @AlexanderDunn please try my answer :]

Comment: @AlexanderDunn are you still getting the same error?

Comment: Yes, still getting the same error. This isnt due to the classes being a default class? Like this:
`export default class OrderView extends Component`

Comment: You'd have gotten a different error if that's the case. Do you have a repo/sandbox with the full code somewhere? Seems like you're still not assigning/passing correctly `updateChargeDates` at some level.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot test the code right now but here's my guess:

```
const { updateChargeDates } = this.props;
```

instead of

```
const updateChargeDates = this.props;
```

in `OrderSummary`

---

Also change this in `OrderView.js`:

```
handleChargesDateChange = (e) => () => {
    const date = e.target.value;
    const chargeId = e.target.name;
    console.log(date);
    this.setState({
        updatedChargeDates: [
            ...this.state.updatedChargeDates,
            {[chargeId]: date}
        ]
    })
}
```

Comment: What is the difference here?

Comment: Hm...does it work? To my understanding if you pass parameter of parent to children as `onClick/onChange` function you have to use a curried function

Comment: Looks like you are having another problem with `updateSelectedDate`, according to your error

Answer (score 0):

You have not destructed the updateChargeDates prop in correct way, try this;

```
const { updateChargeDates } = this.props;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now I know generally this error occurs when you dont bind the method to the class, but I am using the => ES6 syntax which I thought does not require this?

You're correct, the ES6 syntax does not require binding the function.
The problem is as the others have stated, that you're incorrectly destructuring `updateChargeDates`, you need to wrap it in {} for it to be destructured.

`const { updateChargeDate } = this.props;`

Take a look at [this](https://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/) if you would like to learn more about ES6 destructuring.

The error message specifically says that the error is on line 19 in DateInput.js. Is that a custom class you have created, or from a third-party library? You need to check that the class actually contains the on-change method, since the error says it is not a function.

Comment: DateInput is a custom class that accepts onChange. I know this as when I originally had the method implemented in the child class I was getting what I expected.